# Detecting back button pressed in cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, back

i have another problem using a cordova plugin (3.2) in android. I create a custom plugin for cordova because the default one does not match with my expectation. I expect to create a custom alert dialog with item and checkboxes in it. Here is the source code:

Javascript:

```
cordova.exec(
        function(listitem) {
            console.log("select: " +interestResultName[listitem]);
            selectedResult.push(interestResultName[listitem]);
        }, 
        function(error) {
            alert("Error Occured");
        }, "AlertList", "showlistitem", interestResultName );
```

Java:

```
public class AlertList extends CordovaPlugin {
public AlertList() {
}
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if(action.equals("showlistitem")) {
        this.loadList(args, callbackContext);
    }
    return true;
}

public void loadList(final JSONArray thelist, final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    final CordovaInterface cordova = this.cordova;

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for( int x = 0; x < thelist.length(); x++) {
                try {
                    list.add( thelist.getString(x) );
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            CharSequence[] items = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);
            boolean[] checkbox = new boolean[list.size()];

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cordova.getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(" ");

            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkbox, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, item);
                    result.setKeepCallback(true);
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;
            alert.show();    
        }
    };
    this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
}
```

}

The problem comes in the onClick method. Since its a checkbox i'm still keep callback open until user pressed back button. However i cannot implement the backbutton function as usual because my java class extends CordovaPlugin instead of Activity. Does anyone can help me with this ?

My expectation is: after user select item he wants and click back button. Then the callback context will send the selected item to my javascript function (the code: selectedResult.push(interestResultName[listitem]); ) .

Thank you,

Hary